# how to add the number to existing field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a points table and I need to update the values based on the performance . Is possible to do

**table**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "points": 34
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "points": 63
  }
]
```

**query**

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 1
},
{
  "$set": {
    "points": "points" + 10
  }
})
```

**expected output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1,
    "points": 44
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "id": 1,
    "points": 63
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/):

```
db.collection.update({
  id: 1
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "points": 10
  }
})
```

There is no `$dec` for decrementing, instead use `$inc` with a negative number.

Are you actually using mongoose? It looks like a plain mongo node driver query. If you have a Mongoose Model, you can use [`updateMany`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-updateMany)

Comment: Is this not applicable for mongoose

Comment: @AsZik the `$inc` works with the mongoose `updateMany` too. That would look something like `Collection.updateMany({id: 1}, {$inc: {points: 10}})`. Mongoose is just a library for making MongoDB interaction easier. You can use the MongoDB documentation for operations you can do through Mongoose methods